# multiple input tags. Label and text fileds are coming in different lines

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a query builder. I should create multiple text boxes where user types something and data need to be filtered accordingly.

The moment user adds a constraint I have to make its corresponding text field visible.

Problem I have seen is labels and text fields are coming in different lines depending on screen size/resolution.

```
    <div>
        Color Code:<input type="text">
        Material Code:<input type="text">
        No Of Pins:<input type="text">
        Part Number:<input type="text">
        Status:<input type="text">
        Type Code:<input type="text">
        Unit Of Measure:<input type="text">
  </div>
```

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/RaghuY/b4Q47/)

Is there any way I can restrict both label and text field comes in same line?

I don't want them to come in different lines. They should come in one line and if the screen is over then it should start appear on second line ...etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should use tables,line breaks to organize content on html pages.

Comment: @Raju you should not suggest to use tables for such issues.

Comment: @Ravimallya I was not pointing to the exact issue here.It was just a suggestion to organize the content.Otherwise I would have given it as as answer.

Comment: I don't want them to come in different lines. They should come in one line and if the screen is over then it should start appear on second line ...etc.

Answer (score 2):

As you commented, what you need is `display: inline-block;` for `li` element which will wrap up, if it falls short of the viewport `width`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/b4Q47/20/)

```
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

---

You are using inline elements, and thus all the elements render side by side, also, your approach is incorrect here, instead of using those elements straight away, wrap them inside `ul` and `li`, use a `label` tag and set your `label` element to `inline-block`, this way it will align the elements one after the other, and also it will be semantiacally correct.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/b4Q47/1/)

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label for="color">Color Code</label>
        <input type="text" id="color" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="material">Material Code</label>
        <input type="text" id="material" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Style

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul li label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Good approach Mr. Alien. I was also on the way to give similar answer :)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div>
        <label>Color Code:</label><input type="text"><br/>
        <label>Material Code:</label><input type="text"><br/>
        <label>No Of Pins:</label><input type="text"><br/>
        <label>Part Number:</label><input type="text"><br/>
        <label>Status:</label><input type="text"><br/>
        <label>Type Code:</label><input type="text"><br/>
        <label>Unit Of Measure:</label><input type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
label{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/b4Q47/8/

Comment: we are supposed to use `label` tags for texts for input fields right? It is a semantic approach to do so.

Comment: I don't want them to come in different lines. They should come in one line and if the screen is over then it should start appear on second line ...etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a .row div for each line:

HTML:

```
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <span>Color Code:</span>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span>Material Code:</span>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span>No Of Pins:</span>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span>Part Number:</span>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span>Status:</span>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span>Type Code:</span>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span>Unit Of Measure:</span>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
form .row span { width: 130px; display: inline-block; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/b4Q47/13/

Answer (score 0):

A set of label/control pairs logically constitutes a matrix with two columns. The most obvious solution of making it an HTML table also solves your immediate problem, since a table is by default rendered so that each row ends with a line break.

```
 <table>
 <tr><th><label for=color>Color Code:</label> <td><input type="text" id=color>
 <tr><th><label for=mat>Material Code:</label> <td><input type="text" id=mat>
 ...
 </table>
```

This is also a good starting point for styling.

There are many other ways of causing line breaks, but this is the natural approach here.

Answer (score -1):

Add a `<br />` after each `<input />`.

Comment: what if each line will be added dynamically? it will add an extra `<br />` at the end of the last field right?